# Suggestions for speeding up MSSQL JOINED query

Tags: sql-server, join, server, union

Where I work the database has been "touched" by a few different people who no longer work here.  Some of the database views run very slowly.  I assume it is because of the many JOINS and UNIONS it uses.  It seems to me there should be a more efficient way of doing this.  Forgive my lack of knowledge in this area.

```
        SELECT  s.id                    AS 'ShipmentID',
                s.tracking_no           AS 'Tracking Number',
                c.name                  AS 'Client Name',
             ...
            many more
             ...

        FROM    shipments_archive s
                left join client c on c.id = s.client
                left join DIM_ClientCompany cc on cc.client_id = s.client
                left join company co on co.company_id = cc.company_id
                left join weekof wo on CAST(s.date_shipped AS DATE) = CAST(wo.mydate AS DATE)
                left join DIM_ResolutionCodes res on res.Resolution_Key = s.resolutions

            WHERE
                co.company_name NOT IN ('client1', 'client2')

        UNION ALL

        SELECT  s.id                    AS 'ShipmentID',
                s.tracking_no           AS 'Tracking Number',
                c.name                  AS 'Client Name',
             ...
            many more
             ...
        FROM     shipments_archive s
                 left join client c on c.id = s.client
                 left join DIM_ClientCompany cc on cc.client_id = s.client
                 left join company co on co.company_id = cc.company_id
                 left join weekof wo on CAST(s.date_shipped AS DATE) = CAST(wo.mydate AS DATE)
                 left join DIM_ResolutionCodes res on res.Resolution_Key = s.resolutions

        WHERE co.company_name IN ('Client3', 'Client4')

        UNION ALL

        SELECT  s.id                    AS 'ShipmentID',
                s.tracking_no           AS 'Tracking Number',
                c.name                  AS 'Client Name',
             ...
            many more
             ...
        FROM    shipments_archive s
                left join client c on c.id = s.client
                left join DIM_ClientCompany cc on cc.client_id = s.client
                left join company co on co.company_id = cc.company_id
                left join DIM_Pharmacy p on p.company_id = co.company_id and p.[Lookup] = s.shipper
                left join weekof wo on CAST(s.date_shipped AS DATE) = CAST(wo.mydate AS DATE)
                left join DIM_ResolutionCodes res on res.Resolution_Key = s.resolutions
        WHERE co.company_name IN ('Client5')

        UNION ALL
```

Could you not use **GOTO**'s or **CASE** statements.  It just seems very time consuming to be pulling this data multiple times for each client. There is over 5 million records.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The best thing to do here is to look at the plan for the query. This will immediately tell you if there are missing indexes, or potential index tweaks you can use to improve the performance. The fact that the joins are DIFFERENT in each segment of the union tells me it would be error prone to try and combine them all into one select with CASE statements. I will say that JOINING on a CAST() function is going to be a performance killer right there. It might be better to add a computed column that is the DATE part, and add an index on that (with covering INCLUDE columns as required).

Comment: Thanks, I will def try that.

Comment: Just a reminder: Always look at the plan first. I highly recommend "SQL Query Plan Explorer", a free tool that gives you even more insight than SQL Server Management Studio's plan viewer. It color-codes expensive nodes and makes them pop out at you. You can then work to eliminate unnecessary key-lookups (with covering include columns on base indexes) and see where pain points are (table scans, JOINS on functions or type conversions, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From an index perspective, as the comments suggest, taking a look at the execution plan will provide some good insight into how to optimize indexes for this query. From a TSQL perspective, I don't like seeing the same from statements being used multiple times. One option is to use a table variable. It will use more memory but save IO. With that said, I would review the UNION ALL statements as it looks like this query will return duplicate records (company name not in 1 & 2, and company name not in 3 & 4 both return records for client 5).

```
--This will create a table in memory and populate it from the source tables. This way, you only read the source tables once.
DECLARE @table_variable TABLE (
ShipmentID INT
,TrackingNumber INT
,etc...)

INSERT @table_variable (ShipmentID, TrackingNumber, etc...)

SELECT
    s.id AS 'ShipmentID'
    ,s.tracking_no AS 'Tracking Number'
    ,c.name AS 'Client Name'
    --...
    --many more
    --...
FROM shipments_archive s
left join client c on c.id = s.client
left join DIM_ClientCompany cc on cc.client_id = s.client
left join company co on co.company_id = cc.company_id
left join weekof wo on CAST(s.date_shipped AS DATE) = CAST(wo.mydate AS DATE)
left join DIM_ResolutionCodes res on res.Resolution_Key = s.resolutions

--You then select from the table in memory for your subsets.
SELECT
    ShipmentID
    ,TrackingNumber
    ,etc...
    --...
    --many more
    --...
FROM @table_variable
WHERE company_name NOT IN ('client1', 'client2')

UNION ALL

SELECT
    ShipmentID
    ,TrackingNumber
    ,etc...
    --...
    --many more
    --...
FROM @table_variable
WHERE company_name NOT IN ('client3', 'client4')

UNION ALL

SELECT
    ShipmentID
    ,TrackingNumber
    ,etc...
    --...
    --many more
    --...
FROM @table_variable
WHERE company_name NOT IN ('client5')
```

Comment: Thanks for all the great help.  I am going to check out the execution plan and then get the info back here.  Thanks again.